# Is multiprocessing in celery more expensive than multithreading?

Tags: celery

May be this question is not fitting into the stackoverflow FAQ

The reason I am asking this question is that a senior developer came in to the team and started saying that we should move our code to a custom threadpool manager instead of relying on celery to do asynchronous multiprocessing

We love celery because it is so easy. But the argument seems valid, mostly because we do not want to give up on efficiency.

Is it true that since celery uses multiple processes instead of multiple threads, we are loosing on efficiency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, look at [doc](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celeryd-force-execv):

> On Unix the processes pool will fork, so that child processes start
>   with the same memory as the parent process.

Secondly, Celery can more. It may use microthreads. Read [page](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/concurrency/eventlet.html) about how does it

Finally, we can say that microthreads more efficiency than threads, and threads more efficiency processes. But you must remember it depends also from hardware configuration